# How to customise description of NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I would like to provide my own implementation for `description` method of NSArray class, so that I could use it simply like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", @[]);
```

My idea was to provide a category for `NSArray` and simply override `description` method there. However it doesn't work because `NSArray` is a class cluster and its real class is `__NSArrayI`, so my category implementation is never called. Unfortunately I cannot provide a category for `__NSArrayI` because this class is unavailable.

Of course, I can just subclass `NSArray` and implement this method in my subclass, but again, since `NSArray` is a class cluster I have to provide an implementation for a bunch of different methods, like `objectAtIndex:` and I don't wanna do that because this is too much work for simply changing the way an array is printed into console.

Do you have any ideas, guys? Thanks

Comment: You've pretty much gone through the options and the downsides.  I don't think there are any other options.  I suppose you can swizzle, but you may have to live with incomplete coverage, unless you can exhaustively cover all class cluster members.  And remember NSMutableArray is also a class cluster :)

Comment: If you want to do this for a specific array in a specific design then it will probably be simplest to write a method/function to generate the description in either the array's owner, wether that is a ViewController or a wrapper object for the array, or in some other special class which is designed to describe this collection -(NSString *)describeMyArray:(NSArray*)array{...}

Comment: Why do you want to provide a custom `description`? What's the goal? There's probably a better solution to the problem than tacking on functionality to a base collection class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you have any ideas, guys? Thanks

Ideas we got.  Solutions... you gotta decide.

From the [documentation about format specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), you can't just worry about `description`.  Specifically, from that document...

> Objective-C object, printed as the string returned by
>   descriptionWithLocale: if available, or description otherwise. Also
>   works with CFTypeRef objects, returning the result of the
>   CFCopyDescription function.

We can't do much about `CFTypeRef` objects unless we want to hack with the linker and/or dynamic loader.

However, we can do *something* about `description` and `descriptionWithLocale:`, though that something is a bit gnarly.

You may also want to consider `debugDescription` as well.

This is one way to approach your goal, though I consider it "educational" and you should use your best judgement as to whether you want to go this route or not.

First, you need to determine what your replacement `description` implementation would look like.  We will declare a simplistic replacement for `description` like so (ignoring the original implementation).

```
static NSString * swizzledDescription(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    NSUInteger count = [self count];
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Array instance (%p) of type %@ with %lu elements", (void*)self, NSStringFromClass([self class]), (unsigned long)count];
    int fmtLen = snprintf(0,0,"%lu",count);
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        [result appendFormat:@"\n%p: %*lu: %@", (void*)self, fmtLen, i, self[i]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

and an even more simplistic implementation of `descriptionWithLocale:` that completely ignores the locale.

```
static NSString * swizzledDescriptionWithLocale(id self, SEL _cmd, id locale) {
    return swizzledDescription(self, _cmd);
}
```

Now, how do we make the `NSArray` implementations use this code?  One approach is to find all subclasses of `NSArray` and replace their methods...

```
static void swizzleMethod(Class class, SEL selector, IMP newImp) {
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(class, selector);
    if (method) {
        IMP origImp = method_getImplementation(method);
        if (origImp != newImp) {
            method_setImplementation(method, newImp);
        }
    }
}

static void swizzleArrayDescriptions() {
    int numClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);
    if (numClasses <= 0) return;
    Class *classes = (__unsafe_unretained Class *)malloc(sizeof(Class) * numClasses);
    numClasses = objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses);

    Class target = [NSArray class];
    for (int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
        for (Class c = classes[i]; c; c = class_getSuperclass(c)) {
            if (c == target) {
                c = classes[i];
                swizzleMethod(c, @selector(description), (IMP)swizzledDescription);
                swizzleMethod(c, @selector(descriptionWithLocale:), (IMP)swizzledDescriptionWithLocale);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    free(classes);
}
```

A reasonable place to call `swizzleArrayDescriptions` is in your app delegate's `+initialize` method.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [AppDelegate class]) {
        swizzleArrayDescriptions();
    }
}
```

Now, you should be able to play with it and see how you get along.

As a very simple test...

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSArray *array = @[@"One", @"Two", @3, @"4", @"FIVE", @(6.0), @".7.", @8, @9, @10, @"Eleven" ];
    NSLog(@"%@", array);
    NSLog(@"%@", [array mutableCopy]);
}
```

yields this output...

```
2015-11-08 14:30:45.501 TestApp[72183:25861219] Array instance (0x6000000c5780) of type __NSArrayI with 11 elements
0x6000000c5780:  0: One
0x6000000c5780:  1: Two
0x6000000c5780:  2: 3
0x6000000c5780:  3: 4
0x6000000c5780:  4: FIVE
0x6000000c5780:  5: 6
0x6000000c5780:  6: .7.
0x6000000c5780:  7: 8
0x6000000c5780:  8: 9
0x6000000c5780:  9: 10
0x6000000c5780: 10: Eleven
2015-11-08 14:30:45.501 TestApp[72183:25861219] Array instance (0x600000045580) of type __NSArrayM with 11 elements
0x600000045580:  0: One
0x600000045580:  1: Two
0x600000045580:  2: 3
0x600000045580:  3: 4
0x600000045580:  4: FIVE
0x600000045580:  5: 6
0x600000045580:  6: .7.
0x600000045580:  7: 8
0x600000045580:  8: 9
0x600000045580:  9: 10
0x600000045580: 10: Eleven
```

Of course, you should do more testing than I did, because all I did was hack this up after church because it seemed somewhat interesting (it's raining so the picnic was cancelled).

If you need to invoke the original implementation, you will need to create a cache of the original implementations, keyed by class, and invoke them accordingly.  However, for a case like this where you want to modify the returned string, you probably don't need to do that, and it should be straight forward in any event.

Also, please note the normal cautions about swizzling, and they are a bit more heightened when playing with class clusters.

**Note**, that you could also do something like this to create custom subclasses at runtime as well.  You could even define your subclasses just as straight subclasses of `NSArray` in the normal way, then swizzle their types without impacting any of the classes that are not yours... or a bunch of different things... remember the ObjectiveC runtime is your friend.